# Why we are using <!DOCTYPE html> in every Html document?

Tags: html

Why we are using  in every Html  document? . 
Without that doctype also it is  executing the website , then why we have to mention that doctype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE>` - 
**Definition and Usage** 
The  declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the  tag.

The  declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

In HTML 4.01, the  declaration refers to a DTD, because HTML 4.01 was based on SGML. The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

HTML5 is not based on SGML, and therefore does not require a reference to a DTD.

Tip: Always add the  declaration to your HTML documents, so that the browser knows what type of document to expect.

From : [W3 schools HTML  Declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Answer (score 0):

< !DOCTYPE html> -- 
is html5 standard.
By declaring like that your saying to webpage that it is html page which can browser read.

If you see any pdf or xml other text files also browser can read, so by adding DOCTYPE in html, we are this is html document to browser